# CSS Using the contains and first-child selector together

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use the contains selector in css and the first child selector together and can't get it to work. It works without the :first-child selector which makes me think maybe its just not possible? For my example below I only want the first p with the id of taco to have a background-color of yellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p[id*="taco"]:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p>This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (div).</p>
<p>This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (div).</p>
<p id="taco">This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p id="taco">This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p id="taco">This paragraph is the first child of its parent (div).</p>
<p id="taco">This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (div).</p>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use both selectors. I tried using the first child without the contains selector and it worked. I also tried to use the contains selector without the first child selector and that works but using them together doesn't.

Comment: this is just a suggestion: you can use `p#taco` instead, which is better than `[id*="taco"]` also class is better

Comment: First, IDs must be unique on the page. Can't use more than one of the same (for the code to be valid). Use classes instead.

Comment: You're violating the protocol/standard by having multiple #ID's. Once you fix that, you should find an easy solution

Comment: Note to respond to these comments: taco is just a stand in the actual ID are all unique like #context_write, #context_read, #context_get. So my selector is actually [id*="context"]. I would add a class to the elements but i'm writing css to alter a 3rd party dashboard and don't have access to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does work.

What it does is just not what you would expect. CSS is looking for an element which is both `:first-child` and `[id*="taco"]`.

You don't have any first-child containing `taco` in the id.

```
<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>
```

doesn't contain `taco` in the id.

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do but I guess you rather wanna get the first element with a certain id than the `:first-child`. Id's however should remain unique so I would recommend using a class instead.

Therefore you look for something like the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector, though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/2804367) explains why it might also not work as you would expect with other parameters. I hope this does actually help you find a solution for your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two rules.

The first targets the element to modify.

The second keeps the following elements unchanged.

```css
p.taco {
  background-color: yellow;
}

p.taco ~ p {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p>This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (div).</p>
<p>This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (div).</p>
<p class="taco">This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p class="taco">This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (body).</p>
<p class="taco">This paragraph is the first child of its parent (div).</p>
<p class="taco">This paragraph is not the first child of its parent (div).</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't answer my question that I asked BUT it did give me an alternative solution to my problem so thank you so much!